# If you dig a deep tunnel, will the rock sublimate?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, earth, phase-diagram

If a tunnel is dug deep inside the crust (but before reaching places where the rock is liquid), how will the enormous downwards pressure manifest itself? Will the difference in pressure $(\rho_{rock}-\rho_{air})gh$ cause sublimation of the rock, in order to reach thermal equilibrium?

Comment: Is the tunnel being dug vertically or horizontally (or in some other direction)?

Comment: Well, every solid has a vapor pressure. But sublimate? No, more likely it will collapse the tunnel first. Or the rock could melt from sudden pressure release. But I highly doubt there would be noticeable sublimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

As @Jim said, the heat would weaken the rock, which would cause a tunnel collapse before any sublimation could occur.  Also, remember that the air in the tunnel would generally be at the same temperature as the rock (unless a large cooling system was put in), so thermal equilibrium would be maintained without any sublimation.

Comment: So, the reason I didn't make my comment into an answer is because I didn't have any wherewithal to back it up. I agree with the answer, but I kinda hoped an answer would come with more hard science and/or references. Or even a longer explanation

Comment: @Jim I doubt any experiments have been done on this, and I don't know of any equations etc.  I have a tendency to logic answers instead of looking for research, and I also follow the doctrine of "when in doubt, answer - the worst that will happen is no votes".  If you think that I should get rid of this, I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm not going to make any recommendations about what you should do. For the record, the worst that can happen is not no votes. The worst is downvotes and a flag that results in deletion. But you don't have to worry about that here

Comment: @Jim You are right (I even thought of this while writing the comment), but as long as the answer isn't completely off-base or spam, etc. I don't worry about downvotes, like you said.